# Store images in Javascript object

Tags: javascript, html, image, xhtml

I am not sure if this is possible, but I want to store an image in a JavaScript variable or an object and when the page loads, I want to make those images appear where desired.

I want to know if some images are converted to binary form. Can they be converted back to images with JavaScript?

Comment: i dont think its possible, although luca's method can be used to create object, but that object will only contain the image's location not the image itself.

Comment: it will contain a reference to the image itself.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It appears that the OP is requesting how to do data islands in JavaScript, specifically for images. None of the answers previously given provide such a method, so here you go.

Basically, you encode the image as a base64 string and then set that as the source of a DOM element.  Setting the source of an `Image` object to a url is not equivalent, since it requires an addition HTTP connection.

```
var data = 'data:image/gif;base64,'+
    'R0lGODlhAAEwAMQAAJ2M5Me98GRK1DoYyYBr3PHv++Pe99XO81Y50auc6PBkZEgpzbmt7HJa2I57'+
            // snip //
    'fS3CqU7XGYgE+GqHvrLJ8Tr6qXmqiwAF9CffgnMNqmWHAWNBwwGsKpKsrmJqltOOV69nuYxSkqpo'+
    'Tata18rWtrr1rTIIAQA7';
var icon_elem = document.getElementById("icon_here");
icon_elem.src = data;
```

The above code and a full example can be found here: http://www.kawa.net/works/js/data-scheme/base64-e.html

Answer (score 16):

You can simply use

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://yourimage.jpg";
```

to create a DOM image.

A DOM image is an object in memory that contains the image binary form, so there's no need to convert it back to an image since it's already one.

Comment: Thanks for reply, however my needs restrict me to refer to image with absolute / relative path.
Think of it in a way that I want to store the image somehow ?? in the HTML page itself.
I am not sure if it's even possible.

Comment: The only way to reference an image is through a path. How else would you get the image?

Comment: Cuz in your scenario and assuming the browser doesn't cache, every time you assign the the URL to src and then put it in DOM, wouldn't that require implicit reloading?

Comment: @MohammedJoraid No it won't be reloaded. A DOM image is loaded when it is assigned a src, and subsequently assigning the same src to an img tag in the DOM will not result in a reload.

Answer (score 0):

See, this is a simple matter. But the method to approach this problem is not the way you are trying right now.

What you think will work:
We'll store the image (its binary data) in a js variable, and then slap it on the page any time.

How it will work much more easily:
you just have to create a DOM image on the page, and set its source. The browser will fetch the image from the server automatically.

Examples:

ex-1:

```
var img_src = "http://someserver/yourimage.png";
var node = document.getElementById('the-node-in-which-i-want-my-image');
node.innerHTML = "<img src='"+img_src+"' alt='my image'>";
```

ex-2: (using jquery) - this is essentially the same as above, only much easier to write:

```
var img_src = "http://someserver/yourimage.png";
$('#the-node-in-which-i-want-my-image')
    .html("<img src='"+img_src+"' alt='my image'>");
```

Now, there's one more thing: the browser starts fetching the image *after* this code runs, so the image actually appears a little after you insert it into the DOM.

To prevent this, you can pre-fetch the images using:

```
var prefetch = new Image();
prefetch.src = "http://someserver/yourimage.png";
```

Cheers!