# Jquery, Add png data into src attr~

Tags: php, jquery

in php file,

```
...
...
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image1);
```

in html using jquery,(after loading, insert the image data)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
            "url": 'righturl/thephp.php',
            "type": 'POST',
            "data": {},
            "success":function(result){
                $("#hey").attr({"src":result});
            }
        })
});
```

but this makes just binary data inserted.
can not see the image.

```
<img id="hey" src="�PNG  ��� IHDR������������j��� �IDATx�<�ٳ��q��U�[����}���eV�u0�@�Hɔ��P���?9�;�7�[M��D"�7`���C����=��ݷ����[m�~hH�P�|*��9'�����]X߸z���'v���?�w����/jQ�k�Ӗ��I����U��sOO������NǾ�M:�`H�!~���O^9����k�����w{W��k��<�����^��O��o���߄�4�#\�������ݟ�,/�q�ة�����H ����{�mC�N��4��ifl�@"�(�j�y9��|��իW��3���KKM-�����Ν;[��Q1��H� !z���4*-��������VVVvG��~#���Ή��A����`S���X3�a6A�00KCD�1���|���ML�&5��G�Rk���N��a�����E��>�ӡ�<�H1��P3#hA�Y�03(��LD���$Q��Ss#i*FEq�UC�����hQ7�E...1��Y�@���T�7q�?���&31HL�O��4������������3 �rj�鳗�U�Z�E�����(WC�on��7_M늽�|�]0��*v}@36�{�<�(��g�@��o@2%"F�"$��`2�QIfQ-b�rB33W$&�_�a�4l[kvy���5�)"A-�<:��:r�� ��^|�%��kJYUcJf��ui�6�� �̌��TTPA#��u�n�,�;�s���6 ��Y �R���AqВ}Q� �>`(�,}a��d]Rfed�FhH���U9q�U��t������b2"O�Kyc��<�m�1_:[Y��Tm�����߮���q�ic�q��yv:�ǁ��{�A�d#5K>��yo���5�������W-N��ߡ��eT�7���ۣ��Ӄ���A�bhH۾�m/+��ٔ�Lr`EjU�UI!眽3��~+���rZU؋����90����"$c�ө;����F���(}���g�����??훵�aG�ˢ�F)�zM�m2w�����D��|����IEND�B`�">
```

any idea to insert the image data into src attr dynamically?

Comment: You'd probably be better off saving the image locally in your PHP file then returning the path back to the AJAX call. Much less messy that way.

Comment: I know the way, but management of those created images is not easy, so I am trying to do that this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need something like

```
<img id="hey" src="righturl/thephp.php" />
```

So if it must be jquery

```
$("#hey").attr({"src":"righturl/thephp.php"});
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: this should be work, but this doesn't work for me. I am using codeigniter uri in fact.

Comment: paste the url directly to the browser's address bar and what could you see?

Comment: wow, it works. Thank you hope_is_grim. I tried like this before "$this->getPngImg();", this doesn't work. but direct url work.  <img src="/login/getPngImg"/> ^^;

Answer (score 1):

To insert an image data direct into a src attribute will never work. The attribute expect a value with type of string only. Try [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395765/store-images-in-javascript-object) instead.

Comment: Properbly http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php -the comments- will also be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to base64 encode your image data and use the [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
```