# Saving a image from javascript variable

Tags: javascript, image, save

Is there any way to save a javascript variable which contains a image?

```
var image = new Image();
```

If yes,How?

Thanks in advance

Edit:I want to save it as a png without asking the user to do a right click.

Comment: How do you want to save it? Could you provide an example?

Comment: I believe you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395765/store-images-in-javascript-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that by encoding the image into a base64 string, after that you can set that string as the source of a DOM element. 
to encode image you may use some extra tool for that, or you may use this site to generate base64 string for you: http://www.kawa.net/works/js/data-scheme/base64-e.html

After getting your base64 string, you can use it like this:

```
var data = 'data:image/gif;base64,' + 'put your base64 string here';
var icon_elem = document.getElementById("icon_here");
icon_elem.src = data;
```

I hope this may help you