# javascript select image from img tag without reloading image

Tags: javascript

I have a fairly specific problem. I need to select image from an img tag without reloading. I need to use the image in canvas, but i need the same image that is grabbed the first time becouse it's auto generated and changes every time.

Example:

```
<img src="generated_image.php" id="pic"/>
```

Now, i've tried to find a solution, but every page i find suggests to use:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = document.getElementById('pic').src;
```

With that solution javascript grabs the image from url, and since the image at the other side of the url is automaticaly generated it changes.

Is there any way to select image from memory instead of from server?

P.S. Same thing happens when i right click and use save as. Currently the only way i could think of doing this was to right click the image, click Copy image, then paste into paint and save it. Unfortunately, i can't expect my client to do it that way. Thank you.

P.P.S. i have no access to server side image generation, so i have to do it on my end. I prefer clean javascript, but if there are any libraries that could do this i'll happily use them.

Thank you,
Ivan

Current code:

```
if (canvas.getContext) {
    ctx_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx=ctx_canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
    img.src = document.getElementById('image').src;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to do this in javascript?

Comment: I'd prefer to do it in javascript, but might do it some other way if needed.

Comment: insertusernamehere Added current code to question.

Comment: What if you save image in memory as base64? like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395765/store-images-in-javascript-object

Comment: mansim I'm allready using images in memory. I've extracted from memory here to show the problem in a simpler way. The problem was with getting initial image into memory, but that was actually a lot easier than i expected(in selected answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (but note, that the server must serve image with Access-Control-Allow-Origin header)

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("preview");
ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
alert(c.toDataURL());
```

Comment: This actually worked. Used:

ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('image'), 0, 0);

Feel a bit stupid now :) Thank you.