# How to upload and store images in array on a server in node.js and socket.io

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

In my HTML we have an input field that is a file and it is only going to accept images from users. How can we store the images uploaded by the users in the server using only JavaScript and no database? Is this even possible?

```
<input type="file" id="img" name="pic" accept="image/*">

var img = document.getElementById("img");

btn.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    var foodItem = 
    {
        name: food.value,
        location: location.value,
        deal: deal.value,
        votes: 0,
        image: img.value
    };
    console.log(img.value);
    socket.emit("addFood", foodItem);
```

Comment: You need to convert the image to base64 encoding and store it on your server. Use a file if you dont want a database. This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395765/store-images-in-javascript-object

Comment: You can save the images as a regular file in the file system of the server.