# Creating an object with an image as an attribute. Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am creating a user profile that looks like this:

```
export class User{
public email: string;
public name: string;
public location: number;
public intro: string;
public image: //???

constructor(email: string, name: string, location: number, intro:string){
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.intro = intro;
    this.image = //???
    }

}
```

How do I an image here like this, So I can save it in a back end and render into HTML later?

Comment: may be we can get some help from this question: [store-images-in-javascript-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395765/store-images-in-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the url of the image which is of type string ,

```
export class User{
public email: string;
public name: string;
public location: number;
public intro: string;
public image: string;

constructor(email: string, name: string, location: number, intro:string, image:string){
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.intro = intro;
    this.image = image;
    }

}
```

and then you can display as,

```
<img [src]="user.image" />
```

Comment: and in case your img src is blocked by `DomSanitizer` you need to sanitize the date with DomSanitizer  function `bypassSecurityTrustUrl`